# Redis mass insert with tls

Tags: redis

Im trying to run a mass insertion in Redis instance (5.0.8) with tls enabled

I am running this command

`cat import.txt | redis-cli -h <my_host> -p <port> --tls --cert my.crt --key my.key --cacert proxy.pem -a <password> --pipe`

Reply I get is below:

```
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
No replies for 30 seconds: exiting.
errors: 1, replies: 0
```

If I run monitor command from redis-cli it only shows that the above command only authenticates and does not send any more command

Contents of import.txt

```
*5
$3
SET
$4
KEY1
$27
{"key":"value","foo":"bar"}
$2
EX
$2
60
*5
$3
SET
$4
KEY2
$27
{"key":"value","foo":"bar"}
$2
EX
$2
60
*
```

Comment: Your protocol looks wrong to me. It should start with `*5` surely if you are doing `set key1 JSON ex 60`. Do you have both CR and LF at the ends?

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, The protocol does start with *5 (updated the question). And yes I do have \r\n at the end. I tried the same thing with a redis instance that does not have TLS enabled and it worked. I think I am missing something for TLS.

Answer (score 0):

The TLS support for `redis-cli` with `--pipe` introduced in [Redis 6.0.6](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/6.0/00-RELEASENOTES)